# How to truncate sentence of words into particular position

Tags: java, html-parsing

Based on the title, what I'm doing now is extracting data from HTML using Java which I've done. Problem is, the data I extracted contains information which I don't need

Given below is the part of HTML code which I'm extracting

```
<div class="postdetails">
Member Group: Junior Member<br />
Joined: Mar 2010
</div>
```

The output now I'm getting now is `Member Group: Junior Member Joined: Mar 2010` which is both line.

What I want is the `Mar 2010` part. May I know how I can truncate the sentence?

Below is part of my Java code on extracting the data

```
Elements joinDate = doc.select("div.postdetails");

System.out.println(joinDate.text());
```

Comment: 1. String[] arr =String.split(":"). 2.  use arr[2].trim().

Comment: @X86 With simple modification on the code you give me, I managed to get it. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps using `joinDate.text()` isn't the best option? I don't know what other methods your `doc`'s class might have, but I'm pretty sure it should have a method to get all the child nodes, so basically you're looking for the third child node (text `Joined: Mar 2010`) and then you'll want to get the `.text()` property of that node and split it as others have said. While their solution seems to work in this particular case, it is not maintainable and might break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are wanting the text after the last ':' then you can use

```
var n = str.lastIndexOf(":");
```

and then use `str.substr(n)`